# How to create a proper database structure for domains and subdomains?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a list of domains and list of subdomains. For example:

domain A has subdomains a1, a2, a3.
domain B has subdomain b1, b2, b3.
domain C has no subdomains

I need to create database structure so I can order it like so:

A
a1
a2
a3
B
b1
C

And I need to see clearly which one is domain or subdomain of what domain.

I tried to put domains in one table and subdomains in other table with ForeignKey to domain.

```
class Domain(Base):
    __tablename__ = "domains"
    domain_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(), unique=True)


class Subdomain(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subdomains"
    subdomain_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(), unique=True)
    domain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('domains.domain_id'))
```

I'm using domains and subdomains from both of this table to crate third table:

```
class Title(Base):
    __tablename__ = "titles"
    title_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    domain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('domains.domain_id'))
    subdomain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('subdomains.subdomain_id')) -- NULL if that is a Domain
    title = Column(String())
    status = Column(Integer())
```

Comment: First of all, there is no need for the `parent_domain_id` in your `domains1` table assuming that this will house your main domains (ex./ A, B, C, etc...) and also assuming that for example "B" can't belong to "A". From there, we haven't seen your query but you can always sort alphabetically, or use a `CASE` statement in your `ORDER BY` to get the desired sorting (or some variation of this depending on your DBMS).

Comment: What is the query you are using to retrieve the "sorted" data? I assume this is an ORM? Can you update the post with the language/software you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a datamodel and a SQL query.

You can use two tables:

- domain (domain_id, name)
- subdomain (subdomain_id, name, domain_id)

with this query:

```
select name
from
(
  select name, name as domain_name, 'domain' as type
  from domain
  union all
  select sd.name, d.name as domain_name, 'subdomain' as type
  from domain d
  join subdomain sd on sd.domain_id = d.domain_id
)
order by domain_name, type, name;
```

Or just one table:

- domain (domain_id, name, parent_domain_id)

with this query:

```
select name
from
(
  select name, name as domain_name, 'domain' as type
  from domain
  where parent_domain_id is null
  union all
  select sd.name, d.name as domain_name, 'subdomain' as type
  from domain d
  join domain sd on sd.parent_domain_id = d.domain_id
)
order by domain_name, type, name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Thorsten, I tried first one, it's almost perfect: A a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 B c1 c2 c3 C. But I'm looking for A a1 a2 a3 B b1 b2 b3 C c1 c2 c3.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. I've added a type for sorting ('domain' comes before 'subdomain' in the alphabet), so you always get the domain before its subdomains no matter what the name.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's works. Could you please add one more join to first query to get titles from third table?

Comment: So far you have shown two source tables (domains1 and domains2; Im using domain and subdomain instead) and you want some title to appear in the result (in order to build a new table called titles from the query result). Where does the title come from?

Comment: Please check it one more time. I have edited my original post.

Comment: Still there are two source tables without a title column and one target table with a title column. Where does it come from? What is it supposed to contain? Do you merely want to create an empty column?

Comment: Imagine Titles as my log table. I  take all domains and subdomains check their titles, status etc. and fill the Titles table with this data. Then I need to retrieve this data in a form mentioned earlier (Domain > Subdomains). Please check my first post again, I added some adjustments. Could you please add a third join to Titles table in your first query. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I think you should open a new request. You merely wanted to join two tables and get a special sort. This one I answered. Then you added a third table "titles" as a target table. And somehow you haven't been able to explain where its data stems from. Please look at your request. You say there are only two source tables, "domains" and "subdomains". There is no third table. Table "titles" doesn't exist yet. You want to create this third table "titles" from the query result of the two source tables. But your target table magically contains more information than exists in the source tables.